# Equation of a line passing through 2 lines and a point with one line being the midpoint.

Tags: geometry

I am doing a question at the moment for A level Maths and the question gives 2 lines, $L_{1}:\ y=-3x-10$ and $L_{2}:\ y=5x-4$ as well as a point $A=(4,2)$.

It is asked that you find the equation of the line that passes through the point and crosses both lines with $L_{2}$ as the midpoint of $AB$ ($B$ is on $L_{1}$)

I am stuck and sure there must be an equation that does this but I don't know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the co-ordinates of *B* be *(a,b)* and *C* be the mid-point of the line segment AB.

So, $C = C(\frac{a+4}{2},\frac{2+b}{2})$

As, B lies on $L_1$,

$ b = -3a - 10 ...(1)$

As C lies on $L_2$,

$\frac{2+b}{2} = 5.\frac{a+4}{2} - 4 $

$2+b = 5(a+4) - 8$..(2)$

$b = 5a+10...(2)$

On solving (1) and (2),

$a = \frac{-5}{2}$, $b = \frac{-5}{2}$

So, $B= B(-5/2, -5/2)$

Equation of AB is,

$ y - b = \frac{4-b}{2-a} (x - a)$

$y+5/2 = \frac{13}{9}(x + 5/2)$

You may simplify further if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterize $L_1$, e.g., as $(0,-10)+t(1,-3)$. Let this be the variable point $B$ at which the line that you’re supposed to find intersects $L_1$. The midpoint of $AB$ is then $\frac12(t+4,-3t-8)$. Plugging this point into the equation for $L_2$ will give you a simple equation in $t$ to solve. Once you know $t$, it’s a simple matter to come up with an equation of the line through $A$ and the resulting $B$.